# Force HDMI output to monitor with corrupt EDID in Windows 10

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, edid

My TV is not recognised by my windows laptop when i hook it on trough HDMI. I suspect that the EDID registery on my tv is corrupt. The reason for the suspicion is the fact that the TV used to work with my previous laptop (which is unfortunately broken), but i had to force a certain resolution and other settings. As i remember, it was recognised as 'Unkown monitor' or something resembling that.

The difference now is that the monitor is not recognised at all, even not with wrong resultion. It cannot be found in the device manager, and not trough certain tools that read EDID configurations from the registery (i tried [this](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwkMKVlrbRAhWLHxoKHVy7BjsQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.monitortests.com%2Fforum%2FThread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU&usg=AFQjCNHkvu8DdVs62lO78IvRFKmkBbvb6w) tool).

The HDMI port on the TV is not entirely broken, since it works with my cable decoder and XBOX. I suspect these devices do not enforce an EDID handshake and just only 'send' to the monitor.

I found several posts on the internet which attempt to fix the EDID on the TV, which i consider to be too technical for me to undertake.

Given the fact that the decoder and Xbox (and previous laptop) are able to produce image on the tv, i got the feeling that i should somehow be able to bypass an EDID handshake, and be able to force output to the screen on my windows computer.

Any direction in how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!